# Inequality, derivates

Tags: inequality, derivatives

$f,g:[0,\infty)$ functions
$f(0) \lt g(0)$ and $f'(x) \lt g'(x)$ for any $x\in [0,\infty)$.
Does this means that $f(x) \lt g(x)$ for any $x\in [0,\infty)$? And can I use this without proof? I need it in a bigger problem.

Comment: Yes, it is true.  But whether or not you can use it without proof depends on context.  Is this a HW problem?

Comment: Yes, it's a homework problem. For me is naturally true, but i often consider naturally true stuff that need proof

Comment: You can prove it by reducing to $h(0)>0$ and $h'(x)>0$ $\forall$ $x>0$ $\Rightarrow$ $h(x)>0$ $\forall$ $x>0$.

Comment: Argue by contradiction and use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Always simple thinks are hardest to proof for me